# Thread-safe way to use preloaded data in a for-loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, thread-safety, factory

Suppose we apply a set of (inplace) operations within a for-loop on mostly the same fudamental data (mutable). What is a memory efficient (and thread safe) way to do so?

Note the fundamental data should not be altered within the for-loop from iteration to iteration.

**Example Code:**

Assume we have some Excel files containing fundamental data in a `data` directory. Further we have some addtional data in the `some_more_data` directory. I want to apply operations on the data retrieved from the `data` directory using the files from the `some_more_data` directory. Afterwards I want to print the results to a new pickle file.

```
import copy
import pickle
import pandas as pd

# Excel import function to obtain dictionary of pandas DataFrames.
def read_data(info_dict):

   data_dict = dict()
   for dname, dpath in info_dict.items():
       data_dict[dname] = pd.read_excel(dpath, index_col=0)

   return data_dict

# list of data files
data_list = {'price': 'data/price.xlsx', 'eps': 'data/eps.xlsx'}
raw_data = read_data(data_list)

# list of files used for operation (they, for example, have different indices)
some_more_data= {
    'some_data_a': 'some_more_data/some_data_a.xlsx',
    'some_data_b': 'some_more_data/some_data_b.xlsx'
    }
some_more_data = read_data(some_more_data)

# Apply operation to data (explicitly use a for-loop)
for smd_k, smd_v in some_more_data.items():
   rdata = copy.deepcopy(raw_data)

   rdata['price'] = rdata['price'].reindex(smd_v.index)
   rdata['eps'] = rdata['eps'].reindex(columns=smd_v.columns)

   with open(f'data/changed_{smd_k}.pkl', 'wb') as handle:
        pickle.dump(rdata, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Is the deepcopy operation in my example above thread safe (assuming I want to use Multithreading)? Or should I repeatedly load the data from Excel within the for loop  (very slow)? Or is there an even better way?

Thank you for your help.

---

**Code to Generate Sample DataFrames and Save Data in Excel Files**

Note that the directories `data`  and `some_more_data` must be created manually first

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


price = pd.DataFrame([[-1.332298,  0.396217,  0.574269, -0.679972, -0.470584,  0.234379],
                      [-0.222567,  0.281202, -0.505856, -1.392477,  0.941539,  0.974867],
                      [-1.139867, -0.458111, -0.999498,  1.920840,  0.478174, -0.315904],
                      [-0.189720, -0.542432, -0.471642,  1.506206, -1.506439,  0.301714]],
                     columns=['IBM', 'MSFT', 'APPL', 'ORCL','FB','TWTR'], 
                     index=pd.date_range('2000', freq='D', periods=4))

eps = pd.DataFrame([[-1.91,  1.63,  0.51, -.32, -0.84,  0.37],
                      [-0.56,  0.02, 0.56, 1.77,  0.99,  0.97],
                      [-1.67, -0.41, -0.98,  1.20,  0.74, -0.04],
                      [-0.80, -0.43, -0.12,  1.06, 1.59,  0.34]],
                     columns=['IBM', 'MSFT', 'APPL', 'ORCL','FB','TWTR'], 
                     index=pd.date_range('2000', freq='D', periods=4))

some_data_a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(4, 6)), columns=['IBM', 'MSFT', 'APPL', 'ORCL','FB','TWTR'], index=pd.date_range('2001', freq='D', periods=4))
some_data_b = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(20, 6)), columns=['GM', 'TSLA', 'IBM', 'MSFT', 'APPL', 'ORCL'], index=pd.date_range('2000', freq='D', periods=20))

price.to_excel('data/price.xlsx')
eps.to_excel('data/eps.xlsx')
some_data_a.to_excel('some_more_data/some_data_a.xlsx')
some_data_b.to_excel('some_more_data/some_data_b.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once your `raw_data` dictionary has been created, I don't see where it is ever modified (after all, that *is* the point of using `deepcopy` on it). So while deep-copying a mutable object is not thread safe, this particular object is not undergoing mutation at any time. So I don't see why there would be an issue. But, you could always do the `deepcopy` under control of a lock if you were not confident.

If you are doing this with multithreading, then using a `threading.Lock` is probably not going to cost you in performance since the deepcopy operation is all CPU and you cannot achieve any `deepcopy` parallelism anyway because your thread is already locking on the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) for that function (it is primarily Python bytecode). This additional locking just prevents giving up your time slice while in the middle of a `deepcopy` operation to another thread that might begin a `deepcopy` operation (but again, I still don't think that is an issue). But if you are using multithreading, then what performance increase will you be getting from doing concurrent I/O operations? Depending on whether you have a hard disk drive or solid state drive and what the characteristics of that drive is, concurrency might even hurt your I/O performance. You may get some performance improvement from the `Pandas` operations if they release the GIL.

Multiprocessing, which does provide true parallelism of CPU-intensive functions, has its own overhead in the creation of the processes and in passing data from one address space to another (i.e. one process to another). This additional overhead that you do not have in serial processing has to be compensated for by the savings achieved by parallelizing your calculations. It's not clear from what you have shown, if that is indeed representative of your actual situation, that you would gain anything from that parallelism. But, then, of course, you would not have to worry about the thread safety of `deepcopy` since once each process has a copy of `raw_data` that process would be running a single thread with its own copy of memory totally isolated from one another.

**Summary**

1. In general, `deepcopy` is not thread safe for mutable objects but since your object does not appear to be "mutating", it shouldn't be an issue. But if running under multithreading, you could do the `deepcopy` operation as an atomic operation under control of a `multithreading.Lock` without any significant loss in performance.
2. If you are using multiprocessing, and assuming `raw_data` was not being implemented in shared memory, then each process would be working on its own copy of `raw_data` to begin with. So even if another process were "mutating" `raw_data`, as long as any one process was running a single thread, there is no need to worry about the thread safety of `deepcopy`.
3. It's not clear whether multithreading or multiprocessing will achieve any performance improvements based on the code I have seen.

**Benchmark**

This benchmarks serial, multithreading and multiprocessing. Perhaps with only 2 keys in each dictionary this is not a realistic example but it gives a general idea:

```py
import copy
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import time
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool, ThreadPool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count


# Excel import function to obtain dictionary of pandas DataFrames.
def read_data(info_dict):

   data_dict = dict()
   for dname, dpath in info_dict.items():
       data_dict[dname] = pd.read_excel(dpath, index_col=0)

   return data_dict

def serial(raw_data, some_more_data, suffix):
    # Apply operation to data (explicitly use a for-loop)
    for smd_k, smd_v in some_more_data.items():
       rdata = copy.deepcopy(raw_data)

       rdata['price'] = rdata['price'].reindex(smd_v.index)
       rdata['eps'] = rdata['eps'].reindex(columns=smd_v.columns)

       with open(f'data/changed_{smd_k}_{suffix}.pkl', 'wb') as handle:
            pickle.dump(rdata, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

def init_pool(r_d, sfx):
    global raw_data, suffix
    raw_data = r_d
    suffix = sfx

def worker(smd_k, smd_v):
    rdata = copy.deepcopy(raw_data)

    rdata['price'] = rdata['price'].reindex(smd_v.index)
    rdata['eps'] = rdata['eps'].reindex(columns=smd_v.columns)

    with open(f'data/changed_{smd_k}_{suffix}.pkl', 'wb') as handle:
         pickle.dump(rdata, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

def benchmark1(raw_data, some_more_data):
    start_time = time.time()
    serial(raw_data, some_more_data, '1')
    elapsed = time.time() - start_time
    print('Serial time:', elapsed)

def benchmark2(raw_data, some_more_data):
    start_time = time.time()
    items = list(some_more_data.items())
    pool_size = len(items)
    pool = ThreadPool(pool_size, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(raw_data, '2'))
    pool.starmap(worker, items)
    elapsed = time.time() - start_time
    print('Multithreading time:', elapsed)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

def benchmark3(raw_data, some_more_data):
    start_time = time.time()
    items = list(some_more_data.items())
    pool_size = min(len(items), cpu_count())
    pool = Pool(pool_size, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(raw_data, '3'))
    pool.starmap(worker, items)
    elapsed = time.time() - start_time
    print('Multiprocessing time:', elapsed)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

def main():
# list of data files
    data_list = {'price': 'data/price.xlsx', 'eps': 'data/eps.xlsx'}
    raw_data = read_data(data_list)

    # list of files used for operation (they, for example, have different indices)
    some_more_data= {
        'some_data_a': 'some_more_data/some_data_a.xlsx',
        'some_data_b': 'some_more_data/some_data_b.xlsx'
        }
    some_more_data = read_data(some_more_data)

    benchmark1(raw_data, some_more_data)
    benchmark2(raw_data, some_more_data)
    benchmark3(raw_data, some_more_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
Serial time: 0.002997159957885742
Multithreading time: 0.013999462127685547
Multiprocessing time: 0.7790002822875977
```

Comment: what about pandas.DataFrame.copy? By default pandas makes a deep copy of the dataframe. Although it does not deep copy objects in a dataframe like copy.deepcopy would, there should be no objects in a dataframe created with pandas.read_excel(). It would be interesting to see if the df.copy() method delivers similar benchmarks to the Standard Library?

Answer (score 1):

Following up on my own comment and borrowing from @booboo's excellent example.

Try changing these two lines so that instead of

`rdata = copy.deepcopy(raw_data)`

Use

`rdata = raw_data.copy()`

The docs say [pandas.dataFrame.copy()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) creates a deep copy of the dataframe. If there are objects in the dataframe, pandas uses references for those objects. Because your data contains no objects, no references will be used.

It does look to me like pandas.dataFrame.copy()  delivers slightly better performance over the standard library.

with `pandas.dataFrame.copy()` it prints

```
Serial time: 0.0017809867858886719
Multithreading time: 0.009797096252441406
Multiprocessing time: 0.3455531597137451
```

With `copy.deepcopy(raw_data)` it prints

```
Serial time: 0.0018610954284667969
Multithreading time: 0.01049661636352539
Multiprocessing time: 0.34659790992736816
```

It's not a big difference but it is a little faster. Since you're already using pandas, it would be one less library to import, and may also be more efficient for memory use than the standard library. For making deep copies of the dataFrames it is slightly better than than the system library as long as the dataFrames are used to store data and not to store objects.